# animation-delay not working on css

Tags: html, css, animation, delay, fadein

In the snippet provided below, the `animation-delay` property is not working. My word is fading in, so the animation is working, but I want the letters to come at different times.

**Code Snippet:**

```css
.title {
  font-size: 4.5em;
  letter-spacing: 1.5px;
  color: black;
}
.position {
  position: absolute;
  top: 500px;
  left: 100px;
}
.fade-in {
  opacity: 1;
  animation-name: fadeInOpacity;
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
  animation-timing-function: ease-in;
  animation-duration: 2s;
}
@keyframes fadeInOpacity {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
.fade-in span:nth-child(1) {
  animation-delay: 400ms;
}
.fade-in span:nth-child(2) {
  animation-delay: 1200ms;
}
.fade-in span:nth-child(3) {
  animation-delay: 800ms;
}
.fade-in span:nth-child(4) {
  animation-delay: 300ms;
}
.fade-in span:nth-child(5) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 700ms;
}
.fade-in span:nth-child(6) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 600ms;
}
.fade-in span:nth-child(7) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 400ms;
}
.fade-in span:nth-child(8) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 900ms;
}
.fade-in span:nth-child(9) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 700ms;
}
```

```html
<div class="fade-in title position">
  <span>A</span><span>N</span><span>I</span><span>M</span><span>A</span><span>T</span><span>I</span><span>O</span><span>N</span>
</div>
```

---

A couple of things to say. I am testing on safari, but for some reason it works without `-webkit-` on it, although I read somewhere that you need it. I am fairly new so not sure, but just in case I left it out on some of my child elements to test that it's not the problem. It doesn't work regardless. Something to note is that I have tried replacing the whole statement for the attribute color, like so:

```
.fade-in span:nth-child(1)  { color:red; }
.fade-in span:nth-child(2)  { color: green; }
```

and the letters do come in at different colors, so I am reaching my child elements, but for some reason the delay is not working. What am I forgeting? Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should fade the `span`, not the `div`, so I changed the rule `.fade-in` to `.fade-in span`, changed `opacity` to 0 so they start hidden and added `animation-fill-mode: forwards` so they stay visible

```css
.title {
  font-size: 4.5em;
  letter-spacing: 1.5px;
  color: black;
}
.position {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100px;
  left: 100px;
}
.fade-in span {
  opacity: 0;
  animation-name: fadeInOpacity;
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
  animation-timing-function: ease-in;
  animation-duration: 2s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
@keyframes fadeInOpacity {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
.fade-in span:nth-child(1) {
  animation-delay: 400ms;
}
.fade-in span:nth-child(2) {
  animation-delay: 1200ms;
}
.fade-in span:nth-child(3) {
  animation-delay: 800ms;
}
.fade-in span:nth-child(4) {
  animation-delay: 300ms;
}
.fade-in span:nth-child(5) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 700ms;
}
.fade-in span:nth-child(6) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 600ms;
}
.fade-in span:nth-child(7) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 400ms;
}
.fade-in span:nth-child(8) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 900ms;
}
.fade-in span:nth-child(9) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 700ms;
}
```

```html
<div class="fade-in title position">
  <span>A</span><span>N</span><span>I</span><span>M</span><span>A</span><span>T</span><span>I</span><span>O</span><span>N</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Why are my animation-delays not working?**

Your selector is wrong.

Change:

```
.fade-in {
      opacity: 1;
      animation-name: fadeInOpacity;
      animation-iteration-count: 1;
      animation-timing-function: ease-in;
      animation-duration: 2s;
}
```

To this (using [**`animation`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/animation) shorthand to reduce code):

```
.fade-in span{
      opacity: 0; /* Initially hide letter */
      animation: fadeInOpacity 2s 1 ease-in forwards;
}
```

Notice how the key value `forwards` is used. This is the [**`animation-fill-mode`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/animation-fill-mode).

> forwards The target will retain the computed values set by the last
>   keyframe encountered during execution. The last keyframe encountered
>   depends on the value of animation-direction and
>   animation-iteration-count:

Code Snippet:

```css
.title {
  font-size: 4.5em;
  letter-spacing: 1.5px;
  color: black;
}
.position {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100px;
  left: 100px;
}
.fade-in span {
  opacity: 0;
  animation: fadeInOpacity 2s 1 ease-in forwards;
}
@keyframes fadeInOpacity {
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
.fade-in span:nth-child(1) {
  animation-delay: 400ms;
}
.fade-in span:nth-child(2) {
  animation-delay: 1200ms;
}
.fade-in span:nth-child(3) {
  animation-delay: 800ms;
}
.fade-in span:nth-child(4) {
  animation-delay: 300ms;
}
.fade-in span:nth-child(5) {
  animation-delay: 700ms;
}
.fade-in span:nth-child(6) {
  animation-delay: 600ms;
}
.fade-in span:nth-child(7) {
  animation-delay: 400ms;
}
.fade-in span:nth-child(8) {
  animation-delay: 900ms;
}
.fade-in span:nth-child(9) {
  animation-delay: 700ms;
}
```

```html
<div class="fade-in title position">
  <span>A</span><span>N</span><span>I</span><span>M</span><span>A</span><span>T</span><span>I</span><span>O</span><span>N</span>
</div>
```

**Do I need to use [vendor prefixes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Vendor_Prefix) in the `animation` property?**

It depends on the browser support you require. If you are going to use it, always declare the property without prefix **below**.

```
  .fade-in span{
          opacity: 1;
          -webkit-animation: fadeInOpacity 2s 1 ease-in forwards;
          animation: fadeInOpacity 2s 1 ease-in forwards;
    }
```

Here's a really good tool for this. [**Autoprefixer CSS online**](https://autoprefixer.github.io/).

---

**NOTES:**

According to the [**Animation spec**](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-animations/#keyframes):

> If a ‘0%’ or ‘from’ keyframe is not specified, then the user agent
>   constructs a ‘0%’ keyframe using the computed values of the properties
>   being animated. If a ‘100%’ or ‘to’ keyframe is not specified, then
>   the user agent constructs a ‘100%’ keyframe using the computed values
>   of the properties being animated.

This means it is not necessary to declare a property twice, both in your selector and in your animation. Code can be reduced, below is an example.

This:

```
.fade-in span{
      opacity: 0;
      animation: fadeInOpacity 2s 1 ease-in forwards;
}

@keyframes fadeInOpacity {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

Is the same as:

```
.fade-in span{
      opacity: 0;
      animation: fadeInOpacity 2s 1 ease-in forwards;
}

@keyframes fadeInOpacity {
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

Don't repeat yourself ([**DRY**](http://deviq.com/don-t-repeat-yourself/)).

---

### Recommendation:

If the `animation-delay` values are random, I strongly suggest using Javascript.

This will help making the code more maintainable.

I did something similar not so long ago, I'll guide you through if you're interested:

Define the markup:

```
<p id="text">
  Any word or sentence can be here, without wrapping each letter in a span manually.
</p>
```

We want to do two things:

1. Wrap each word in a `<span>` tag to be able to manipulate it individually.
2. Assign a different `animation-delay` on each `<span>` element containing a letter.

---

### STEP 1:

Lets create a JS function with the element, that we want each letter to be wrapped, as a parameter:

```
function letterWrap(el) {}
```

Inside this function we will first get the text from the element we defined up top with an `id="text"` and separate each letter. To achieve this we will use [**`Node.textContent`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent), [**`trim()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Trim) and [**`split()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split).

```
el.textContent.trim().split(''); 
/* Gets element's text, removes whitespace, then separates each letter. */
```

```js
function letterWrap(el) {
  console.log(el.textContent.trim().split(''));
};

var text = document.getElementById("text");
letterWrap(text);
```

```html
<p id="text">
  Animation text goes here.
</p>
```

---

As you can see, `split()` returns an array. We then use the [**map()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) method to:

> provide a callback function once for each element in an array, in
>   order, and constructs a new array from the results.

Using `innerHTML` and what we have so far, we can append each letter into the `<p>` container. In this example we will use the class `.letter` to style each `<span>` tag.

```
 function letterWrap(el) {
              el.innerHTML = el.textContent.split('').map(function(letter) {
                return '<span class=letter>' + letter + '</span>';
              }).join('');
            };
```

```js
            function letterWrap(el) {
              el.innerHTML = el.textContent.split('').map(function(letter) {
                return '<span class=letter>' + letter + '</span>';
              }).join('');
            };

            var text = document.getElementById("text");
            letterWrap(text);
```

```css
.letter:nth-child(odd) {
  color: chartreuse;
}
```

```html
<p id="text">
  Animation
</p>
```

Step 1 is done. We can now go to step two, assign a random `animation-delay` on each letter and set the animation itself.

---

### Step 2:

First, lets select all the elements with the class `letter` we assigned, this will get us a list we can iterate.

```
 var letters = document.getElementsByClassName('letter');
          for (var i = 0; i < letters.length; i++) {
            //Animation delay logic goes here.
          }
```

`animation-delay` logic:

For each letter, multiply the index times a random number between 1 and 100, return this number in miliseconds and assign it to the `animation-delay` property of this element.

```
 letters.item(i).style.animationDelay = i * Math.floor((Math.random() * 100) + 1) + 'ms';
```

We wrap things up and end up with this:

```
 function letterWrap(el) {
          el.innerHTML = el.textContent.split('').map(function(letter) {
            return '<span class=letter>' + letter + '</span>';
          }).join('');
          var letters = document.getElementsByClassName('letter');
          for (var i = 0; i < letters.length; i++) {
            letters.item(i).style.animationDelay = i * Math.floor((Math.random() * 100) + 1) + 'ms';
          }
        };
```

Lets add some styling:

```
/* Layout */
body,
p {
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100vh;
}

/* Letter animations */
#text {
  font-size: 4.5em;
  letter-spacing: 1.5px;
  color: black;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

@keyframes fadeInOpacity {
  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

.letter {
  opacity: 0;
  animation: fadeInOpacity 2s 1 ease-in forwards;
}
```

And we're done!

---

### Code Snippet:

```js
function letterWrap(el) {
  el.innerHTML = el.textContent.split('').map(function(letter) {
    return '<span class=letter>' + letter + '</span>';
  }).join('');
  var letters = document.getElementsByClassName('letter');
  for (var i = 0; i < letters.length; i++) {
    letters.item(i).style.animationDelay = i * Math.floor((Math.random() * 100) + 1) + 'ms';
  }
};

var text = document.getElementById("text");
letterWrap(text);
```

```css
body,
p {
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100vh;
}
#text {
  font-size: 4.5em;
  letter-spacing: 1.5px;
  color: black;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
@keyframes fadeInOpacity {
  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
.letter {
  opacity: 0;
  animation: fadeInOpacity 2s 1 ease-in forwards;
}
```

```html
<p id="text">
  Animation
</p>
```

---

[**jsFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/rickyruizm/464wobqu/)

---

### Playground

Every time you want to use this, you simply select the element and call this function instead of defining a lot of `:nth-child` pseudoclass selectors.

```js
            function letterWrap(el) {
              el.innerHTML = el.textContent.split('').map(function(letter) {
                return '<span class=letter>' + letter + '</span>';
              }).join('');
              var letters = document.getElementsByClassName('letter');
              for (var i = 0; i < letters.length; i++) {
                letters.item(i).style.animationDelay = i * Math.floor((Math.random() * 100) + 1) + 'ms';
              }
            };

            var a = document.getElementById("a"),
              b = document.getElementById("b"),
              c = document.getElementById("c"),
              d = document.getElementById("d");
            letterWrap(a);
            letterWrap(b);
            letterWrap(c);
            letterWrap(d);
```

```css
p {
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
@keyframes fadeInOpacity {
  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
.letter {
  opacity: 0;
  animation: fadeInOpacity 2s 1 ease-in forwards;
}
#a {
  font-size: 1em;
  color: tomato;
}
#b {
  font-size: 1.2em;
  color: chartreuse;
}
#c {
  font-size: .8em;
  color: dodgerblue;
}
#d {
  font-size: 2em;
  color: gold;
}
```

```html
<p id="a">
  Animation
</p>

<p id="b">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
</p>

<p id="c">
  Sed a purus lacinia, condimentum nisi aliquam, porta ex. Proin sed nunc dignissim ex hendrerit iaculis. Donec ut dui pulvinar felis vehicula varius ac sed metus. Integer bibendum purus et ipsum feugiat, vitae luctus ante lobortis.
</p>

<p id="d">
  abcd
</p>
```

Comment: _A common mistake is to declare a property twice._ .. absolutely, but to omit the start value in a `@keyframes` rule is **not** recommended, and is not considered a _mistake_

Comment: "If a 0% or “from” keyframe is not specified, then the user agent constructs a 0% keyframe using the computed values of the properties being animated. If a 100% or “to” keyframe is not specified, then the user agent constructs a 100% keyframe using the computed values of the properties being animated."

Comment: @LGSon This has always been clear to me, but I may be wrong, if you could provide a reference to support what you're saying it would be much appreciated. Probably using the word mistake is not ideal here, will edit. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: The statement you found, _If a 0% or “from” keyframe is not specified, then the user agent constructs..._ is enough, as by doing this you let the browser decide, which can lead to unpredictable result based on how each and every browser will do the construction, hence, IMHO and have been doing this for +20 years, I say not recommended, as I've seen these stuff back fire, and when they do, you don't want to be the responsible developer anymore :)

Comment: They also say ___If___, not ___you may___, which again tells me what they want one to do ... so other than this, I don't know of such official reference explicit saying _you may leave one out_

Comment: As long as the initial property is declared in the class where the animation is set I do not see a problem. I've seen Lea Veriou, Sara Soueidan, and many more front-end developers do this. Generally it may be bad to let the user agent decide because it could cause inconsistency between browsers, but this seems like a solid implementation... Indeed, as always, things can backfire in CSS! Thanks for your experienced input on this, I will definitely take it into account. Maybe I could post this as a question.

Comment: Please do post (if, drop me a note here), there are guys other who beats me by a million when it comes to technical knowledge, so let them shed some light on this

Comment: Here's the [**question**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40366905/is-it-safe-to-remove-a-property-from-the-0-keyframe-of-a-css-animation-if-it). `:)`

Answer (score 0):

You've specified the `-webkit` versions in the wrong order. The `-webkit-animation` replaces the delay rule that you just set up. Reverse the order so that the delay comes after.

```
-webkit-animation:fade-in 5s;
-webkit-animation-delay:15s;
```

You can avoid these issues if you always set a single attribute:

```
-webkit-animation-name: fade-in;
-webkit-animation-duration: 5s;
-webkit-animation-delay: 15s;
```

Don't forget to also set:

```
opacity: 0;
```

Otherwise the text will be visible until the animation starts, and:

```
-webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
```