# css transition highlight optimization

Tags: jquery, css, css-transitions

I'm trying to do an animation so that **on js call** a box will instantly change color and after restore back slowly, I made it, but I think it might not be the optimal solution:

```js
var d = $('#d1');
d.click(function() {
  d.addClass('high');
  setTimeout(function() {
    d.addClass('trans');
    d.removeClass('high');
    setTimeout(function() {
      d.removeClass('trans');
    }, 1000);
  }, 500);
});
```

```css
div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: gray;
}

div.high {
  background: yellow;
}

.trans {
  transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='d1'></div>
<br> click on the box
```

can this be made with less js / more optimal solution ?

(I'm using click in this demo, but I need to do this on js function call)

Comment: This looks like a candidate for Code Review, though perhaps not in its current form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on Temani Afif's answer, here's an alternative approach that makes use of the animationend event instead of a timeout:

```js
var d = $('#d1');
d.click(function() {
  d.addClass('high');
}).on('animationend', function() {
  d.removeClass('high');
});
```

```css
div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: gray;
}

div.high {
  animation: highlight 1.5s ease-in-out;
}

@keyframes highlight {
  0%, 33% {
    background: yellow;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='d1'></div>
click on the box
```

Comment: nice one but the only *small* issue is that you have to specify the same background inside the animation as the div and thus you cannot reuse the same animation with another element. By the way i know that with my solution i had to specify the same duration in JS which also not good :)

Comment: @Temani Afif: Yeah, that's annoying. Maybe I'll just stick to what you have, though I did adjust the duration and percentages to bring it a little bit closer to the original timings.

Comment: @Temani Afif: Wait... you went and edited your answer while I was editing mine. D'oh. That's why we have separate answers.

Comment: i simply edit to improve the JS part based on your answer :) in case most people only check the accepted answer so better know there is down a better alternative. I also linked to your answer

Comment: @Temani Afif: People will have to scroll either way so it's either I delete my answer or I submit my edit and roll yours back...

Answer (score 3):

You can simplify with a CSS animation:

```js
var d = $('#d1');
d.click(function() {
  d.addClass('high');
  /* No need to remove if you want it to happen one time*/
  setTimeout(function() {
    d.removeClass('high');
  }, 1000);
  /**/
});
```

```css
div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: gray;
}

div.high {
  animation: anim 1s ease-in-out;
}

@keyframes anim {
  0%,
  50% {
    background: yellow;
  }
  /* We only specify to 50% so it revert back to initial color 
     and thus can be used with different div having different colors
   */
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='d1'></div>
click on the box
```

Comment: Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40366905/is-it-safe-to-remove-a-property-from-the-0-keyframe-of-a-css-animation-if-it/40384562#40384562 for a more detailed explanation of the "revert back to initial color" behavior.

Answer (score -1):

Here it is, just css-y way, but it work only for the very firs click. Just like for an example, without any js, just for alternative. Do not be strict, please =)

```css
#d1 {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: gray;
}

#d1:focus {
  outline: none;
  animation: anim 1s ease-in-out;
     
}

@keyframes anim {
  0%, 
  50% {
    background-color: yellow;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id='d1' tabindex='1'></div>
click on the box
```